# How to override inferred type by Pylance using type annotations?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

Recently I have encountered an issue in VS Code when trying to perform type annotation for variable in a function:

```py
def f(array):
    # Pylance shows the type of b being `Any | list`,
    # which I think should be `list`.
    b: list = array.tolist()
    return b
```

In VS Code, the argument `array` is inferred as `Any`: when we hover on this variable, VS Code pops up a hint showing

```
(paramter) array: Any
```

This is reasonable for me, as I think Pylance implicitly assumes `array` as `Any` type.

But things start to go strange when I try to annotate variable `b` as type `list`. VS Code inferred that the type of `b` was `Any | list`, which I do not understand. I want Pylance to respect to my annotation instead of the inferred `Any`. Why is it that the result is a Union type?

Also, what should I do to let my annotation override the inferred type?

I have tried using `typing.cast`, which solved this problem, but I think this is somehow awkward. What I want is that my annotation could override the inferred type by Pylance.

Comment: This smells like a bug. You explicitly say "`b` is of type `list`", and there are only two ways to go: either issue an error (if assignment is incompatible) or accept your decision (if compatible). There is no "let's think we're wiser than user and create a random union instead". `mypy` does not create such weirdness, your type will be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @STerliakov! I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4936) in the official pylance GitHub repo for this bug.
The reply was that this behavior is intended, and not a bug:

> This behavior is intended, so I don't consider it a bug. I can understand why this appears inconsistent, but there's a good reason for it.
>
> Pyright (the type checker upon which pylance is built) distinguishes between explicit `Any` and implicit `Any`. It refers to the latter as `Unknown` when type checking is enabled. For more details, refer to [this documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/type-inference?id=unknown-type). In most cases, pyright treats `Any` and `Unknown` the same, but in strict type checking mode, it allows you to be notified specifically when you attempt to use an `Unknown` type. The assumption is that if you have explicitly specified `Any`, you have acknowledged that you're foregoing type safety, but if you have an `Unknown` you will want to be told about it. For this reason, pyright retains an `Unknown` when narrowing a type for assignment. In your first example, the type of the parameter `array` is `Unknown` because you haven't provided any type annotation for it. That means the type of the expression `array.tolist()` is also `Unknown`. When assigning this to the variable `result`, its type is narrowed from `list` to `list | Unknown`. This preserves the `Unknown` so if you use this value subsequently and you have strict type checking mode enabled, you will be informed about its use.
>
> When you disable type checking (i.e. set typeCheckingMode to "off") pylance displays `Unknown` as `Any` even though internally the type tracked by pright is `Unknown`.

Pyright is the type checker used in Pylance, and Pyright treats *implicit* `Any` as `Unknown`.
For variables that are `Unknown`, the `Unknown` type will be preserved for operations so that we can be informed that "there exists a variable of partially unknown type".
Moreover, in VS Code when `python.analysis.typeCheckingMode` is set to `off` (which is the default) instead of `basic` or `strict`, `Unknown` will be displayed as `Any`.

So now I think *using Pyright*, to override the inferred type of variable `b` to `list` we need to use `typing.cast`:

```py
b = typing.cast(list, array.tolist())
```

Or we fix the origin of the `Unknown` type (in my example, by annotating `array` as `Any` or `np.ndarray`).